# Is there are javascript function how to know the frontpage url?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Example.

User was in /home.html

redirected to /room.html

press back button in browser(or backspace) -> came back to /home.html

is there a javascript or jquery function to fecth the previous page url?(/room.html)

Comment: Useful thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528324/how-do-you-get-the-previous-url-in-javascript

Comment: You can tell the browser to go back/forward, but you can't get the url's in the history. Check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232863/get-full-url-history-using-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use  [document.referrer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.referrer?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/document.referrer) to get that.

```
string url = document.referrer;
```

**Description:** Returns the URI of the page that linked to this page.

The value is an empty string if the user navigated to the page directly (not through a link, but, for example, via a bookmark). Since this property returns only a string, it does not give you DOM access to the referring page, [Referance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.referrer?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/document.referrer).

Comment: ok so this is how it works. home -> room // it shows home.html   , but room -(backbutton)- home /// doesn't show room.html

Answer (score 0):

> is there a javascript or jquery function to fecth the previous page url?(/room.html)

`window.history.back()` returns you to the previous page

`window.history.forward()` goes forward

check out the `window.history` object

Answer (score 0):

The `back()` method loads the previous URL in the history list.

This is the same as clicking the "Back button" in your browser, or `history.go(-1)`

```
window.history.back()
```